# After adding a Springboot JPA dependency, Maven can't build my JAR file any more

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, spring-data-jpa

So, while learning Springboot, one of the things that came up was working with DBs and the Springboot Data JPA. After adding the simple dependency (with and without the version):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and trying to export/build a jar file, with either STS's export or the "mvn clean install"/"mvn clean package" I get the following:
https://pastebin.com/5qDSGejT

This also happens if the project was just created with STS or Spring Initializr and I really have no idea where to start figuring out what's wrong here.

Comment: did you read the error message, and follow its recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

The database driver is either missing or corrupt.

Or you simply have not setup a connection to a database.

I would suggest you to double check if your database connection is correct and go into your .m2 folder and delete your maven repositories.

You can easily setup a database connection using application.properties which is located in src/main/resources. Spring boot will take care of the rest.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It was something with the database at the point of posting the question, but this is not the whole picture. I was getting a different stack trace yesterday. To reach it again, I added a dependency for a DB. Part of the second error was:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

It seems the problem lies in Java 9 (which I installed just yesterday) and the new "thing" with modules and Jaxb. So in the end, the solution was in another thread here, about jaxb not being included:

```
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This does fix the problem, but this is such a mess of information, it really is just a band-aid solution.